# How can I get objects grouped by start_date and end_date in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Rails.
Thank you so much for checking my question.

What I want to do is to extract the data ordered and grouped by start_date and end_date.

Model:

```
class CreateUserMedicines < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :user_medicines do |t|
    t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
    t.references :medicine, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
    t.date :course_start, null: false
    t.date :course_end, null: false
  end
  add_index :user_medicines, [:user_id, :medicine_id]
  end
end
```

Expected view as each user is like this.

```
+---+------------+-------------+------------+
|   | start_date |  end_date   |  Medicines |
+---+------------+-------------+------------+
| 1 | 2016/09/11 | 2016/10/01  |  A, B, C   |
| 2 | 2016/09/11 | 2016/09/18  |  D, E      |
| 3 | 2016/09/19 | 2016/09/26  |  F         |
+---+------------+-------------+------------+
```

As each medicine (A, B, C), I want to get medicine name and id to add links.

To do this, How do I write controller and model function?

[edit:]
My desired result:

```
{ [ Sun, 11 Sep 2016, Sun, 17 Sep 2016 ]=> [#<UserMedicine:0x007f82c291722>, #<UserMedicine:0x007f82c291349>]
```

Current code and result:

```
record:
@user.user_medicines.group_by(&:course_start)

result:
{ [ Sun, 11 Sep 2016 ]=> [#<UserMedicine:0x007f82c291722>, #<UserMedicine:0x007f82c291349>]
```

Any answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you show an example of your desired result? You should be able to use [group_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) and [order](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order)

Comment: thanks. I want this. 
`{ [ Sun, 11 Sep 2016, Sun, 17 Sep 2016 ]=> [#<UserMedicine:0x007f82c291722>, #<UserMedicine:0x007f82c291349>] `
and this start_date and end_date are desired to be referred for UserMedicine Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass a block to the `group_by` and return an array out of the block

```
@user.user_medicines.group_by { |m| [m.course_start, m.course_end] }
```